# How can I thin out my ice cream mixture?

Tags: ice-cream, blender, consistency

I'm trying to make a McFlurry/Blizzard-like dessert in my blender, but the ice cream isn't coming out at the consistency I'd like. I tried adding milk, but that didn't seem to do much. The ice cream doesn't pour well out of the blender and is kind of clumpy. Is there anything else I can try? Do different types of ice cream behave differently in a blender?

Comment: Are the clumps icy?

Comment: Not that I noticed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the milk and add ice cream till you reach the desired consistency. If you want to add 'bits' start when it is about halfway to the thickness you want

Comment: I will try this next week.